# Transistor Circuit DC Analysis

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis

I am struggling with solving this circuit. 
The current of drain is 1mA, and input impedance is 500k. and we should determine the value of R1 and R2.
I don't know how to write its KVL using input Impedance. could you solve this as an example? 
[image: Circuit]

Comment: I won't solve it for you, but I will tell you that you just need to add to your circuit a voltage source (Vi) in series with a resistor of 500k ohm on the input, and then solve the circuit with that input source.

Comment: thanks, How much should be the value of the voltage source? and should it be connected to ground?

Comment: Yes the voltage source should be connected between ground, and a 500k ohm resistor, the other end of which, is connected to the input. Well the value of the voltage source should be Vi, like in your circuit. If you don't know the numerical value of Vi then you solve the equations with Vi as a variable, and express your results in terms of Vi..

Comment: https://leachlegacy.ece.gatech.edu/ece3050/notes/mosfet/csamp.pdf

Comment: any questions? Danialz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Id=1mA , K= 8 mA/V², Vt=2V

\$V_{GS} =\sqrt{\dfrac{I_D}{K}}+V_t=\sqrt{\dfrac{1mA}{8mA/V^2}}+2V =2.35~V~~~~~~~~2V=Vt=V_{gs(th)}~~~~\$in datasheets has large tolerance

Gate input impedance = \$ 500k = R1//R2   .....(1)    \$

Using KVL:  \$ ~~~~6V=V(R1)+ Vgs +Id*Rs ~~~~,~~~Vgs =V(R2),~~Id*Rs=1V   \$

\$  Vgs=2.35V= \dfrac{R2*(6-1)V}{(R1+R2)}  .........(2) \$

now re-arranging

\$\dfrac{R1+R2}{R2}=\dfrac{5V}{2.35V}  ~~~ , ~~~ \dfrac{R1}{500k}=\dfrac{R1+R2}{R2}\$

Two equations and two unknowns solve R1,R2 using above.

Comment: keep track of your "quality" ??

Comment: I believe your KVL is running in excess of 1g.

Comment: murphy's law ... fixed interim, but correct result TY @SredniVashtar

Comment: ok @SredniVashtar ?

Comment: anybody home out there?

Comment: zzzz... zzzz... uhg! Oh! Er, yes, seems to check (neglecting the negligible current in the divider). What I meant by "excess of 1g" is that if you turned Vgs into Vs (that is the voltage across the 1k resistor), it would have been fine. Seemed like a typo to me. But it's ok in this form as well.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is correct. The previous answer had some issues which is why i removed it as correct answer. Thank u very much and sorry for the delay.